# Mode Function: How does it work?

Tags: c++, arrays, average, bubble-sort

I've recently created a C++ program to find the mean median and mode of an array of values.

I was able to modify a snipbit from something I found online to create a function that generates the mode, or at least the 1st most occurring values it can find, that I was able to implement. However, I am not 100% sure of how to wrap my head around what is actually happening within the function.

A better understanding of what is happening in the mode function would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mode(int[], int);
void mean(int[], int);
void sort(int[], int);
void median(int[], int);

int main()
{

   int array[15];
   float total, mode;
   int n = 15;//number of elements in array

    //fill in the value of array
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << "fill in the "<< i+1 << " number. :";
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    sort(array, n);
    return 0;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void mean(int new_array[], int num){
 //GET TOTAL & CALCULATE MEAN
    float total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<num; i++){
        total += new_array[i];
    }
    cout << "The mean is " << total/num << endl;
    mode(new_array, num);
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void median(int new_array[], int num){
    //CALCULATE THE MEDIAN (middle number)
    if(num % 2 != 0){// is the # of elements odd?
        int temp = ((num+1)/2)-1;
        cout << "The median is " << new_array[temp] << endl;
    }
    else{// then it's even! :)
        cout << "The median is "<< new_array[(num/2)-1] << " and " << new_array[num/2] << endl;
    }
    mean(new_array, num);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void mode(int new_array[], int num) {
    int* ipRepetition = new int[num];
    // alocate a new array in memory of the same size (round about way of defining number of elements by a variable)
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        ipRepetition[i] = 0;//initialize each element to 0
        int j = 0;//
        while ((j < i) && (new_array[i] != new_array[j])) {
            if (new_array[i] != new_array[j]) {
                j++;
            }
        }
        (ipRepetition[j])++;
    }
    int iMaxRepeat = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        if (ipRepetition[i] > ipRepetition[iMaxRepeat]) {
            iMaxRepeat = i;
        }
    }
    cout<< "The mode is " << new_array[iMaxRepeat] << endl;

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void sort(int new_array[], int num){
     //ARRANGE VALUES
    for(int x=0; x<num; x++){
         for(int y=0; y<num-1; y++){
             if(new_array[y]>new_array[y+1]){
                 int temp = new_array[y+1];
                 new_array[y+1] = new_array[y];
                 new_array[y] = temp;
             }
         }
     }
    cout << "List: ";
    for(int i =0; i<num; i++){
        cout << new_array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    median(new_array, num);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: mode is a basic statistical operator; it represents the element with the highest frequency (appears the most times) in an array. This is exactly what your functions does. the usual problem with this operator is how you treat the case where you have more elements with the same frequency which is the highest - here you simply take the first one (as far as I can see)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a very high level, first it leaks memory.

```
int* ipRepetition = new int[num];
```

allocates a new array and nothing calls `delete[]` afterwards.

Second, it fills the new array with zeros by walking through the size of the original array of data one at a time up to the current place it has got to`i`, if `(new_array[i] != new_array[j])` (which it checks twice just to be sure) it increments `j`.

If it finds a match or gets to the end of the elements it has filled so far it adds one to the `ipRepetition` array in position `j`.
This is trying to keep track of how often the number in `new_array` at index `i` is used.

The next `for` loop then walks through these numbers to find the index `i` largest value.

It then prints the value in the original array at this index.

It might be more useful if the function were changed to return the value. Since it is C++ you could use a vector instead to avoid the memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You have two parallel arrays: one for the numbers and one to count the repetitions.

The way repetitions are counted is by iterating through the list up to the current number, stopping at the first match and incrementing its repetition count. Say you have the following array:

5 5 2

On the first iteration, you set the first value of the parallel array to 0, then end up breaking out of the inner loop immediately and incrementing it, leaving you with:

1 ? ?

in the parallel array. In the second iteration, the loop will again break on the first item, because `new_array[1] == new_array[0] == 5`. So you'll be left with:

2 0 ?

...and of course in the third iteration the third value will end up set to 1.

If you still have difficulty understanding, you can think of it like giving one "point" to each number in the original list, then moving the points backwards to the first instance of each number. You could try this on paper even.